# Convert list into a dataframe in timeseries data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How can I convert the following list format into a data frame format? When I try this `pd.DataFrame(input)` I end up with the following error `KeyError: 01`.

input

```
[                     a b c
 2020-03-03 01:00:00  2 1 0,
                     a b c
 2020-03-03 02:00:00  21 11 0,
                     a b c
 2020-03-03 03:00:00  2 11 0,
]
```

output

```
                     a b c
 2020-03-03 01:00:00  2 1 0
 2020-03-03 02:00:00  21 11 0
 2020-03-03 03:00:00  2 11 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your input is a list of dataframes (which you can confirm by doing `type(list[0])` ), in which case you can just do

```
pd.concat(list)
```

Comment: I get this error when I run `type(list[0])` - `IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: can you explain how you got the input, this can help find out what type it is? And if it's a list, what is len(list)?

Answer (score 0):

you input isn't look like a list make sure it is a list you can take reference for Lists
https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists.asp
for check weather it is a list or not use `type(list)` command then you can convert it to a dataframe using below command `pd.DataFrame(list)`.

Comment: It is a list. I just checked. Thannk you for the tip though.

Comment: then you can convert it into list what error you got?

Comment: I mentioned in the question.

Comment: You list should look like below example for convert it to dataframe.

`People_List = [['Jon','Smith',21],['Mark','Brown',38],['Maria','Lee',42],['Jill','Jones',28],['Jack','Ford',55]]

df = DataFrame (People_List,columns=['First_Name','Last_Name','Age'])`